"Popup window closed" on Google GIS requestAccessToken - in Joomla php environment
After succesfully initialising a tokenclient with:
function initializeGoogleSignIn() {
    tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: 'xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
        callback: ''
    });
}


and then calling a requestAccessToken like:
async function loginUser() {
        const tokenResponse = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            tokenClient.callback = (response) => {
                if (response.error) {
                    reject(response); // Reject if there's an error in the response
                } else {
                    resolve(response); // Resolve with the token response
                }
            };
            tokenClient.error_callback = (response) => {
                if (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
                // reject(response); // Reject if there's an error in the response
            };

            // Request access token with a consent prompt
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: 'consent' });
            // tokenClient.requestAccessToken();
        });

        return tokenResponse;
    }


The popup opens and stays open (where i can select the user and so on) but I immediately get an error due to calling the error_callback:
message
:
"Popup window closed"
stack
:
"Error: Popup window closed\n    at new _.qj (https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client:235:232)\n    at Ks.D (https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client:238:365)\n    at lg (https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client:204:193)\n    at _.l.dispatchEvent (https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client:202:348)\n    at _.nj.F (https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client:229:842)"
type
:
"popup_closed"
GIS is checking the state of the popup and throws this error. The 'closed' attribute of the window is 'true' but that seems to be very strange to me.
Who can help on this? Thanks!
It seems the callback function is never called when going through the login process.
Why is this happening? In Google Cloud everything is setup correctly and lgging in to Google is working when finishing the login process.
Addition 25 November 2024
Unfortunate still not solved for me.
I thought maybe it is due to having the DevTools open. I 'simplified' the javascript to:
function initializeGAPI() {
    tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES,
        callback: (response) => {
            console.log(new Date() + ': response: ' + response);
            accessToken = response.access_token;
            searchAndDownloadFiles('$targetdirectory');
        },
        error_callback: (response) => {
            console.log(new Date() + ': response: ' + response);
        },
    });
}

function startDownload() {
    console.log(new Date() + ': start Download');
    tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: 'consent' });
}

Then clicking on the button and walking through the login screen the console tells me:
Mon Nov 25 2024 15:19:17 GMT+0100 (Midden-Europese standaardtijd): start Download
Mon Nov 25 2024 15:19:18 GMT+0100 (Midden-Europese standaardtijd): reponse: Error: Popup window closed
So the callback is never called.
Hopefully someone can help? Why does the gapi'client' gets a closed = true on the opened popup window?
Addition 27 November 2024
If I create a straight html file on my server and call that html directly then the callback is called after logging in.
The javascript above is embedded in a php file which creates the html dynamically on a Joomla5 site. Then the popup closed error shows up immediatly. Why?
